# How to add onclick with parameter to button in Blazor?

Tags: c#, razor, blazor, razor-pages, blazor-server-side

I have the following code in a Blazor server-side app:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Name</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var applicationUser in ApplicationUsers)
            {
                string userId = applicationUser.Id;
                Guid? personId = applicationUser.PersonId;

                <tr>
                    <td>@applicationUser.Email</td>
                    <td>@applicationUser.PersonName</td>
                    @if (personId != null)
                    {
                        <td>
                            <button class="btn btn-block btn-primary" @onclick="() => ShowEditPersonDialog(personId)" style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255); background-color: rgb(49, 56, 215);" @type="button">Edit Person</button>
                        </td>
                    }
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

However this:

`@onclick="() => ShowEditPersonDialog(personId)"`

...doesn't work. As it is above the component loads up until the first button on the first row (there are 4 users - 4 rows should load) then the button doesn't render properly and an unhandled exception is thrown:

[image: Blazor application exception]

I've tried:

- `@onclick="() => ShowEditPersonDialog(personId)"` - exception shown above
- `@onclick="(e) => ShowEditPersonDialog(e, personId)"` - exception shown above
- `@onclick="e => ShowEditPersonDialog(e, personId)"` - exception shown above
- `@onclick="@(e => ShowEditPersonDialog(e, personId))"` - exception shown above
- `@onclick="(e) => ShowEditPersonDialog(e)"` - exception shown above
- `@onclick="e => ShowEditPersonDialog(e)"` - exception shown above
- `@onclick="@(e => ShowEditPersonDialog(e))"` - exception shown above
- `@onclick="() => ShowEditPersonDialog()"` - exception shown above
- `@onclick=@"() => ShowEditPersonDialog(personId)"` - doesn't compile, syntax errors
- `@onclick="@(() => ShowEditPersonDialog(personId))"` - exception shown above
- `onclick="() => ShowEditPersonDialog(personId)"` - compiles, runs and renders but the button doesn't respond
- `onclick="@(() => ShowEditPersonDialog(personId))"` - doesn't compile - Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'object' because it is not a delegate type
- `onclick="(e) => ShowEditPersonDialog(e, personId)"`- compiles, runs and renders but the button doesn't respond
- `onclick="e => ShowEditPersonDialog(e, personId)"` - compiles, runs and renders but the button doesn't respond
- `onclick="@((e) => ShowEditPersonDialog(e, personId))"` - doesn't compile - Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'object' because it is not a delegate type
- `onclick="@(e => ShowEditPersonDialog(e, personId))"` - doesn't compile - Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'object' because it is not a delegate type
- `onclick="@(e => ShowEditPersonDialog(e))"` - doesn't compile - Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'object' because it is not a delegate type

How the hell do I write this thing?? I simply want a button to pass through the relevant personId for the given row to the ShowEditPersonDialog method.

Comment: `@onclick="() => ShowEditPersonDialog(personId)"`

Comment: @Eliseo that results in the exception shown in the question

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Change your button to this - remove the `@` from `type="button"` and use `@onclick="@(() => ShowEditPersonDialog(personId))"`

```
<button class="btn btn-block btn-primary" 
    @onclick="@(() => ShowEditPersonDialog(personId))" 
    style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255); background-color: rgb(49, 56, 215);" 
    type="button">Edit Person</button>
```

Its also good to move your inline button css styles to a class in a css file so the HTML markup is cleaner to read :)

Comment: I think that the `@` in `"@(()=>...."` is unnecesary

Comment: No @Eliseo it's not. Consider this: `@()` - it's an empty expression. So Blazor won't be able to parse beyond `@()` if it's `@() =>`. Hence the second set of ()

Comment: Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/event-handling?view=aspnetcore-3.1#lambda-expressions

Comment: This fixed it! Thank you, I had no idea about the @type="button" being the issue, I've just followed what others have done. The entire solution will be cleaned at some point, I'm just focused on getting it working first.

Comment: @Quango, I just check the `@onclick="() => ShowEditPersonDialog(personId)"` or `@onclick="(() => ShowEditPersonDialog(personId))"`and both works for me -in a very simple application WSAM-